# Parse SID as a parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I have 2 contained databases in Microsoft SQL 2019. In DB01, a user with password has been created:

```
USE DB01
CREATE USER [username] WITH PASSWORD = '1234'
```

In DB02, a user without login/password needs to be created with the same SID.
If I run the command and fill out the SID manually, it works without any issues:

```
USE DB02
CREATE USER [username] WITHOUT LOGIN WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [schema_1], SID = 0x010500000000000903000000AD91E331ECFC284B938E65DAF644BAF6
```

However, if I try to parse the SID as a parameter, it fails with the error "Incorrect syntax near '@usersid'"

```
USE DB01
DECLARE @usersid varbinary(MAX) = (SELECT sid FROM sys.sysusers WHERE name = 'username')
USE DB02
CREATE USER [username] WITHOUT LOGIN WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [schema_1], SID = @usersid
```

Any idea why?

**EDIT**

Following the recommendations of @Stephan (many thanks!!!), I came with the following solution. I had to modify the query a little as the DB names actually come from variables as well. I don't know if it is the best way, but it works :)

```
DECLARE @DB01 nvarchar(30) = 'DB01'
DECLARE @DB02 nvarchar(30) = 'DB02'

DECLARE @usersid varbinary(85)
DECLARE @get_sid nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT @usersid = sid FROM ' + @DB01 + '.sys.database_principals WHERE [name] = ''username'''
EXEC sp_executesql @get_sid, N'@usersid varbinary(85) OUTPUT', @usersid OUTPUT

DECLARE @create_user nvarchar(max) = CONCAT(N'USE ',@DB02,N' CREATE USER [username] WITHOUT LOGIN WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [dbo],SID = ',CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@usersid,1))
EXEC(@create_user)
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: Hi @jarlh, I use Microsoft SQL 2019 + SQL Server Management Studio 18

Comment: Possibly the SID has to be a constant? You might have to resort to dynamic SQL to make use of it.

Comment: sysusers table is deprecated sinc 17 years ! Use : DECLARE @usersid varbinary(256) = (SELECT sid FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = 'T???')

Comment: From the doc, SID = sid means that you have to pass a scalar value. Not a varianble. SO do it with a dynamic SQL EXEC...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others mentioned, you must use dynamic SQL as CREATE USER is not design to accept input parameters, only literal strings.

### Dynamic SQL to Create User with Specific SID

```
DECLARE @UserSID varbinary(85) = (SELECT sid FROM sys.database_principals WHERE [name] = N'UserName');

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = CONCAT(N'CREATE USER [username] WITHOUT LOGIN WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo,SID = ',CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@UserSID,1))

EXEC(@SQL)
```